# Drill through and down the object properties with RTTI

Tags: optimization, delphi, rtti

I am in process of making debugging output better for client-side application. We have lots of auto-generated [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) classes which are used for communication by our protocol.

I am trying to make an function that would enumerate properties in any `TObject` passed to it, and return JSON-alike string that contains values of those properties. Using this, I would be able to fully output any protobuf contents that goes through protocol in debug console.

```
function EnumerateProperties(const AObject: TObject): String;
var
  rt: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  value, value2: TValue;
  valstr: String;
  propstr: String;
  fullstr: String;
  bres: Boolean;
  meth: TRttiMethod;
  bytes: TBytes;
  bytes_arr: TArray<TBytes>;
  uints: TArray<UINT32>;
  C1: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(AObject) then
    Exit('');

  rt := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(AObject.ClassType);

  fullstr := '';
  // iterate through public properties
  for prop in rt.GetDeclaredProperties do
  begin
    value := prop.GetValue(AObject); // get property value
    valstr := '?';

    // check property type
    case prop.PropertyType.TypeKind of
      tkInteger,
      tkInt64,
      tkFloat: valstr := value.AsVariant;

      tkString,
      tkChar,
      tkWChar,
      tkLString,
      tkWString,
      tkUString: valstr := QuotedStr(value.AsString);

      tkEnumeration: begin
        valstr := 'ENUM';
        if value.TryAsType<Boolean>(bres) then
          valstr := BoolToStr(bres, TRUE)
        else
        begin
          valstr := GetEnumName(value.TypeInfo, prop.GetValue(AObject).AsOrdinal);
        end;
      end;

      tkClass: begin
        // check if property is TList or any of its descendants,
        // then iterate through each of it's members
        meth := prop.PropertyType.GetMethod('ToArray');
        if Assigned(meth) then
        begin
          value2 := meth.Invoke(value, []);
          Assert(value2.IsArray);
          for C1 := 0 to value2.GetArrayLength - 1 do
            valstr := valstr + Format('(%s), ', [EnumerateProperties(value2.GetArrayElement(C1).AsObject)]);
          if valstr <> '' then
            Delete(valstr, Length(valstr) - 1, 2);
          valstr := Format('[%s]', [valstr]);
        end
        else // otherwise, process it as normal class
          valstr := Format('[%s]', [EnumerateProperties(value.AsObject)]);
      end;

      // dynamic arrays
      tkDynArray: begin
        if value.TryAsType<TBytes>(bytes) then // TBytes
          valstr := BytesToHex(bytes)
        else
          if value.TryAsType<TArray<TBytes>>(bytes_arr) then // TArray<TBytes>
          begin
            valstr := '';
            for C1 := Low(bytes_arr) to High(bytes_arr) do
              valstr := valstr + QuotedStr(BytesToHex(bytes_arr[C1])) + ', ';
            if valstr <> '' then
              Delete(valstr, Length(valstr) - 1, 2);
            valstr := Format('(%s)', [valstr]);
          end
          else
            if value.TryAsType<TArray<UINT32>>(uints) then // TArray<UINT32>
            begin
              valstr := '';
              for C1 := Low(uints) to High(uints) do
                valstr := valstr + IntToStr(uints[C1]) + ', ';
              if valstr <> '' then
                Delete(valstr, Length(valstr) - 1, 2);
              valstr := Format('(%s)', [valstr]);
            end;
      end;

      tkUnknown: ;
      tkSet: ;
      tkMethod: ;
      tkVariant: ;
      tkArray: ;
      tkRecord: ;
      tkInterface: ;
      tkClassRef: ;
      tkPointer: ;
      tkProcedure: ;
    end;

    propstr := Format('%s: %s', [prop.Name, valstr]);
    fullstr := fullstr + propstr + '; ';
  end;

  if fullstr <> '' then
    Delete(fullstr, Length(fullstr) - 1, 2);

  result := fullstr;
end;
```

The output I get with it is this (yellow line):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BHUGVz5.png]

I rarely worked with RTTI before, so I have little-to-none experience, and this is what I've come up with. I'd like to hear any suggestions, function hasn't been extensively tested, and as you can see, several `tk*` types are not yet implemented.

Also, I have one specifical question: if value type is `tkDynArray`, is it possible to make generic code that would format the array in readable way, instead having to do `TryAsType<>` for each type we use in protocol, and then parse each separately?

Answer (score 2):

I'll just point out that you're kind of re-inventing the wheel here. Delphi has built-in facilities for walking a class's properties and generating a "Json-Like" output in the form of property streaming (Delphi uses this internally for writing and reading `.dfm` files).

Have a look at the `TStream.WriteComponent` method.

Comment: That works only for `TComponent`, and not for `TObject`. Anyhow, I solved the issue with SvSerializer: http://code.google.com/p/delphi-oop/wiki/SvSerializer